# Find out if a String contain a value in an array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, netbeans

Is there a shorter way to find out if your string contains any of the value in a String[]?

This is my code:

```
String s = "Hello world! My name is Bao.";
String[] arr = new String[]{"o", "!", "-", "y", "z"};
for (String item : arr) {
    if (s.contains(item)) {
        System.out.println("String s contains: " + item);
    } else {
        System.out.println("String s doesn't contains: " + item);
    }
}
```

Is there a shorter way of doing this? I don't want to use `for` loop for this.

It may be slow when the array contains 4000+ strings.

Comment: Look into Aho Corasick.

Comment: That depends on what you mean by slow. 4000 is nothing. 4 million on the other hand..

Comment: Can you be more specific on what you mean by shorter? Shorter execution time? Shorter code?

Comment: hmm I tried to use Arrays.asList(arr).indexOf(s);

Comment: but that seem to be comparing if the arr is contains the string...it's not what I wanted :|. and yes I mean by shorter code. :(...like without the for loop for example

Comment: i think you are going in the right direction :)

Comment: Are you using Java 8? If so, you can use a lambda.

Answer (score 0):

For large arrays of Strings, it will be faster first convert your array and target string to a `HashSet`. Being a `Set` will remove duplicate characters, and being `Hash`ed will make comparison very fast. Then you can do a couple of quick set subtractions to get your answer:

```
String s = "Hello world! My name is Bao.";
String[] arr = new String[] { "o", "!", "-", "y", "z" };

Set<String> sSet = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(s.split("(?!^)")));
Set<String> arrSet = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(arr));

Collection<String> notFound = CollectionUtils.subtract(arrSet, sSet);
Collection<String> found = CollectionUtils.subtract(arrSet, notFound);
```